# VBA Excel: AdvancedFilter to get unique values after AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking dropdown values in a criteria range and applying on a data set to filter the data, its working but the value that criteria is searching in the dataset is not unique, like there are 2 values ABC and ABC 1. I have passed ABC in the criteria range but it gives me back data of ABC and ABC 1. Help me in getting this fixed.

.Range("A:" & lcol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Assessment List").Range("Criteria"), Unique:=True

Answer (score 1):

In your Criteria range `Sheets("Assessment List").Range("Criteria")`
Change `ABC`
to `'=ABC`
That should resolve your problem.

Regards,